# How to remove the random white space that UIScrollView is putting between subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to add two custom interfaces that are UIViews to a `UIScrollView` in my mainStoryBoard.

both UIViews have an image inside them, the image's dimensions are equal to the view's dimensions.

This is the code I am using to add these views to my scrollView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.myScrollView.frame = view.frame     

        for i in 0..<2{


            let uiImage = UIImage(named: "\(i)")!  
           let view =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TestView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView

            view.setImage(uiImage)

            let xpos = self.myScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            view.frame = CGRect(x: xpos, y: 0, width: self.myScrollView.frame.width, height: self.myScrollView.frame.height)


            myScrollView.contentSize.width = self.myScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat((i + 1))
            myScrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            myScrollView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            myScrollView.addSubview(view)

        }


    }


}
```

In the `TestView.swift`, I have

```
func setImage(_ name:UIImage) -> Void{

    testUIImage.image = name
    testUIImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    testUIImage.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

But when I run the app, the first View gets added fine, but when i scroll to the right, I can see that the second View is not in the Scrollview properly and there is a white space between the first and second View, almost like the space is an added view, that is pushing the second View to the right. I have paging enabled in the scrollViewer.

[First Image In ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiLvH.png)

[Second Image In ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XHD0.png)

As you can see, the second image is cut off on the leading edge.

This is the blank space between them:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TX1O.png)

I checked the width of both UIView frames, they are equal. I also checked the content size after the second iteration, it is equal to the size of both frames*2 , as it should be. But for some reason, a white black space is being added. And it only shows up after adding 2 or more subviews.

Comment: are both images have same sizing or same aspect ratio ?

Comment: This is the frame setting issue.

Comment: From the description of `scaleAspectFit`: 'The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio'. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.  So your image is being scaled while maintaining it's aspect ratio and doesn't fit exactly.  If you change it to `scaleAspectFill` you will see a difference because this will clip the image instead.

Comment: @Upholder Of Truth, you are right, i was guessing the same but see the first picture of the question. The image's aspect ration is quiet right, it fills width wise the scrollview. And notoriously the second image seems to be the same image but not doing the same job as first. Only the different aspect ratio of both images will play like this. I like your suggestion of using scale to fill, but the output may not look like what OP is expecting, streching the image wherever the space is left.

Comment: @RatulSharker indeed my suggestion of trying `scaleAspectFill` was really just to test if this was the issue not a final solution.  In fact in this case I would refactor the entire code so that the adding of the images was done in the `viewDidLoad` and then the actual layout adjusted in the `willLayoutSubviews`.  I was really just trying to help towards an answer rather than provide one.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth so what would be a concise solution? Thank you.

Comment: @hackerman Can you share your project so i can give it to you back by fixing it ?

Comment: Difficult to provide a simple answer but personally I would look into using a `UIStackView` and adding the test views to that. I would also use auto layout to position everything.  Doing it that way you can add everything to the arranged subviews of the stack view in the `viewDidLoad` and then in `willLayoutSubviews` you just need to set the frame of the stack view itself.